# Table indexes and constraints needlessly recreated when generating migrations in Typorm NestJs

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

In Package.json script tag i have added
`"typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"`

then for migration:
generation i use
`npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -n <migration name>`

to run migration:
`npm run typeorm migration:run`

nest version: 8
orm: Typeorm
database: PostgreSQL

Table indexes and constraints needlessly recreated when generating migrations in Typorm NestJs.

is there any solution to stop this?